# Get a list of containers on Azure blob using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, azure-storage

I am trying to access data in one of the containers on the blob. I have the following entry in my App.config file:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="BlobConnStr" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=acct_name;AccountKey=acct_key" />
</appSettings>
```

and I use the code below:

```
 Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BlobConnStr"))
 Dim blobClient As CloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient()
```

The thing is that I do not know the container name, so I cannot access it from code. I need to retrieve the list of files that are in the container. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally you need to know the name of the container in order to get the blobs in it. If you need to see all the containers available, you can ListContainers from the blobClient and choose one from there. Then, using the container from the list you can call ListBlobs.